# Why am I getting wrong row with INDEX function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: Data]
[image: Formula]

This image is of my data.  I am running an INDEX method to get the invoice number.  It is working on all other rows but this one although they all have the exact same formula.  I eventually found that it is pulling data from the row underneath where it is supposed to.  The formula shows it is pulling from 4 rows above.  I must be missing something with the INDEX function that's making it pull the wrong row for this formula

Here is the page showing the result so you can see the other numbers pulling correctly but this one pulling the "WHAT?" that I entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `MATCH` function is doing a lookup in range `I:I`, that is, column `I` starting at row `1`.  Your `INDEX` range is `A5:N2492` that is, starting at row `5`.  Therefore all results will be offset by 4 rows.  Change `INDEX` to reference `A:N` and you should be Ok

Answer (score 0):

Index gives you the index of the column within the range, is is possible that your range starts four rows lower?

Yeah, it looks like your range is A5:N2492
Which means, if you index 1, then it will return what is in the A5 block.